# Problem with corr() function: nan produced

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, correlation, series

I have the following code below:

```
Correlation = Deaths['Cases'].corr(COVID19['Cases'],method='pearson')
print(Correlation)
```

Which gives me the output:

```
nan
```

I can't understand why this is! Could anyone give me a helping hand?
All in all, I want to see whether there is a correlation between these two series.

The series **Deaths['Cases']** looks like this:

```
242    803
243    732
244    414
Name: Cases, dtype: int64
```

The series **COVID19['Cases']** looks like this:

```
0       966
1     59504
2    148969
Name: Cases, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indices are different, therefore you can't calculate the correlation.

```
Deaths['Cases'].reset_index(drop=True).corr(COVID19['Cases'].reset_index(drop=True), method='pearson')
#-0.9733651275536442
```

Comment: so just to clarify, they're strongly correlated, as one increases, the other decreases.